# Asp .Net Core Load Page even if data hasn't loaded yet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a page which takes a bit of time to load because of fetching data OnGet handler

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    Consumos = await _consumoService.GetAll();
}
```

My question is, I have made it async so the data is loaded in a separated thread, but it still takes some time to even access the page. Why is this ?

Comment: Your `OnGet` handler returns a `Task` - the page isn't rendered and the response isn't returned until this `Task` completes. If you want to render the page and fetch the data separately, you might want to look at the AJAX approach.

Comment: Ah I see, I think i just got myself confused about async/await. I read some documentation but i thought i could still load page while the other thread was fetching data.

Comment: Have you tried having that OnGet in a partial view? and render the partial view asynchronously?

Comment: Could you not display the page without any of the data, then perform an [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to get the data and use JavaScript to alter the markup to display it?

Comment: @nalnpir I don't think you can have codebehind on partial views.

Comment: @Jamie Taylor Yes I had this before but i thought i could do it this way using C#

Comment: how you mean you cant have a code behind? the code behind is just the controller you are calling, as a matter of fact you can have a ViewComponent, and call it asynchronously from any view

Comment: Yes view component can do that but doesn't make sense in this situation. What you meant was basically just get an ajax request from a controller which is what i had before. I just wanted to try it this way which i was wrong about it

Comment: @Jackal you can do it from C#, but it depends on the size of your data set. If the data set is too big, then you'll have to wait for the page to be rendered. Does `Consumos` have a lot of properties?

Comment: it has 7 properties, i assume that is quite a bit to render because the dataset on average consists of 700 to 1000 rows